# How to open MS Access in Runtime using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm struggling on how to open MS Access Runtime using VBA, from an Excel file.

You can open the full version of Access using `CreateObject("Access.Application")`, but that doesn't open Access in Runtime.

We only have Microsoft Access Runtime installed in some computers, because that's all we need to use the front-ends we've developed. So we need to open the accdb files using MS Access Runtime, but from Excel.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "in runtime"? Is Access supposed to magically open with a specific database and run a specific macro without you telling it?

Comment: Yes - we only have Microsoft Access Runtime installed in some computers, because that's all we need to use the front-ends we've developed.So we need to open the accdb files using MS Access Runtime, but from Excel.

Comment: I'd suggest you [edit] your question to include that somewhat crucial information.

Comment: I'll do that - thank you!

Comment: Awesome - down+close votes retracted. And heck, have an upvote!

Comment: Do you need to programmatically interact with the objects? Or is it enough just to open the file? Perhaps using Shell commands?

Comment: Just open the files. I'll look into shell commands, thank you

Comment: **Windows Script Host Object Model** `WshShell.Exec`, or **Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation** `Shell.ShellExecute`

Comment: @ZevSpitz awesome, thanks!!

Comment: @ZevSpitz that would be an answer...

Comment: @Mat'sMug Not really, because it's only clear from the comments that the OP doesn't need programmatic access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Shell to open a file, as if you typed that command into window's command prompt.

```
d = Shell("pathToFile\Database1.accdb /runtime", vbNormalFocus)
```

Another option you could use to open in the file in runtime (if someone opens it from the folder or through some other method without the /runtime switch) would be to change the file extension to .accdr. This will always force runtime.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did something very similar and it's working now
`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run ("""pathToFile\Database1.accdb""")`